# Rails routes alias validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Ruby on Rails 4 application and I have alias for every user. So the user profile url is domain/:alias. My question is how can I validate that :alias doesn't match some of the routes? If I have an url - domain/news, it should loads news#index, not user profile with alias news. Thanks!

Comment: You've been downvoted because the question is very ambiguous

Answer (score 1):

The Rails router will match the *first* route it finds in source-order in your routes.rb. So as long as domain/news is routed before domain/:alias, the news route will take precedence over an alias of “news”.

Note, though, that it is up to you to make sure you never offer a user an alias that won’t work, and that you never add a future route in a site upgrade that blocks an existing user from accessing his or her profile.

Some ways to accomplish this are:

1. Give the profile route some kind of prefix. E.g. `domain/u/:alias`.
2. Use a prefix for *non-user* routes. E.g. `domain/i/news` and blacklist the prefix as an alias. (This is how twitter does it, for example)
3. Force a minimum length on the user alias, and make sure all your system routes are shorter. For instance, if user aliases have to be 8+ characters, then you can name your own routes “help”, “news”, “pages”, “info”, “support”, and so on safely. So long as you create a route that is 8+ characters you will never have an overlap.

Or I’m sure there are a dozen other clever ways to do it. But you must plan ahead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to create a way to have [`clean urls`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL), or [`slugs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL#Slug), in your system

You should have provided your `routes.rb` file - which you'd have something like this inside:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "some_page", to: "controller#action"  # -> pages need to be declared before slug
get ":alias", to: "users#show"
```

This will give you the ability to access `domain.com/user` & be redirected to the `user` `show` action for it